# `dir` to consider only long file names

Tags: cmd

Up till now I thought if I do `dir *.aaa` I will get all files with extension `.aaa`, following proves me wrong:

```
echo >a.aaa
echo >a.aaa_bbb
dir /b *.aaa
```

prints

```
a.aaa
a.aaa_bbb
```

Which is not quite what I expect. I guess this is because `a.aaa_bbb`'s name in 8.3 notation has the `.aaa` extension. How do I force `dir` not to consider 8.3 names? Or please suggest any other way to list files by file mask that does not consider 8.3 names.

UPD: Thank you. Can't mark both answers as accepted, but they both are good.

Comment: `dir /x *.aaa` shows that your guess is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forfiles /M *.aaa` does the trick. There are many parameters to change the output to your needs. See `forfiles /?`

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

```
dir *.aaa /b |findstr /i "\.aaa$"
```

or this: (double the `%` to `%%` for use in a batch file)

```
for %a in (*.aaa) do if /i "%~xa"==".aaa" echo %a
```